# How to debug Perl under Apache with Perl5-IDEA?

Tags: perl, intellij-idea

I suffered through the wiki of Perl5 plugin of IntelliJ IDEA, and this issue: https://github.com/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA/issues/1771 but I couldn't find any solutions.

So how do we config this plugin to be able to debug Perl projects running under Apache mod_perl?

Thank you.

Comment: I would think the first requirement for being able to stop processing at breakpoints would be to either be able to invoke the code from the command line in a way that matches how it's called from Apache, or have Apache hook into an IDE that would wrap the perl debugger around the code (I've no idea if the latter can even be done, but I'd probably look to Padre for any hope of doing that.)  For my own web page debugging, I found logging Data::Dumper output of the arguments and pertinent environment of the calls I was interested in to be invaluable, but too awkward for me to say it's the answer.

Comment: Thanks @EdGrimm. Honestly, I'm looking for something beyond Data::Dumper.

Comment: Me, too. As I said, that''s too awkward to be the answer. I'd like an IDE hook, but when I was last in this situation, there was no such hook I could find. But that said, Padre was still very new at that time, so here's hoping that something has come out since then. :)

Comment: Yeah, we're still hoping.